# Add missing squares when div is resized

Tags: javascript, css

I want to create a div, which has many smaller squares inside of it as such:

[image]

The problem is, is that when I resize my screen, the squares re-adjust making
the rows uneven:

[image]

In that image, I could add 4 more squares, and the div is filled again equally with squares.

So I am wondering how would I add the missing squares on resize.

[Here is a jsfiddle of my project](https://jsfiddle.net/EricTalv/pxkmLqr6/77/)

below is my code laid out:

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
  
for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    
    // create dom elem
    const square = document.createElement("div");
    square.setAttribute("class", "square");
    
    container.appendChild(square);

  }
```

```css
.container {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  gap: 10px;
}

.square {
  min-width: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
 
 
 background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
</div>
```

Comment: What is the criteria here: you always want four rows of boxes? What happens if you resize the screen to make it smaller?

Answer (score 0):

Add flex-grow: 1; on the item (the .square) see if the result fits your needs

Comment: not exactly, with flex grow the bottom most elements will resize their width, but Id like the squares to retain their size.

Comment: and instead of growing add more squares?

Comment: so when the screen shrinks, the squares disappear?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that what you want but this code will let u keep constant number of rows of boxes with constant size for each box

```
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const boxWidth = 40;
const gap = 10;
const padding = 10;
const numberOfRows = 4;
let numberOfBoxes = 0;

window.addEventListener("resize", (e) => {
    renderBoxes();
});

function renderBoxes() {
    const containerWidth = container.clientWidth;
    const boxesPerRow = ~~((containerWidth - padding) / (boxWidth + padding));
    const n = boxesPerRow * numberOfRows;
    if (n != numberOfBoxes) {
        container.innerHTML = "";
        for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            const square = document.createElement("div");
            square.setAttribute("class", "square");
            container.appendChild(square);
        }
    }
}
renderBoxes();
```

`padding` constant refers to padding in one side only, the rest are clear